# How to avoid last \n character in heredoc

Tags: ruby, heredoc

In ruby heredoc:

```
a = <<~TEXT
  asd
  asd
TEXT
```

it will generate:

```
[21] pry(main)> a = <<~TEXT
[21] pry(main)*   asd
[21] pry(main)*   asd
[21] pry(main)* TEXT
=> "asd\n" + "asd\n"
```

It generate a `\n` at the end of string, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As [sagarpandya82 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210829/how-to-avoid-last-n-character-in-heredoc#comment77388895_45210829), you will need an additional action (i.e. `chomp`) to remove that extra `\n`.

You can use `chomp` along with *heredoc* like this:

```
a = <<~TEXT.chomp
  asd
  asd
TEXT
#=> "asd\nasd"
```

Comment: Source: https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents

Answer (score -1):

```
<<-TEXT.squish.squeeze(' ')
  aa
                  b
TEXT
# => "aa b"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/8289918) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.